# WCF service type aliases

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I wonder if it's possible to define some kind of type aliases (e.g. as in [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/)) to have shorter thus less error-prone configs, so instead of this:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="ListenerBehavior" name="Corporation.Solution.Project.Namespace.GenericClass`1[[OtherCorp.Framework.Long.Class.Name, OtherCorp.Framework.Another.Long.Class.Name, Version=3.0.0.39, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]">
  <host>
    <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9485/Listener" />
    </baseAddresses>
  </host>
</service>
```

I would have something like this:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="ListenerBehavior" name="ServiceTypeAlias">
  <host>
    <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9485/Listener" />
    </baseAddresses>
  </host>
</service>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could go for Unity that allows you to use Type Alias

Have a look at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660933(PandP.20).aspx#_Type_Aliases

you have add the below to your configuration file to define the alias you want to use

```
<unity>
<typeAliases> 
  <typeAlias alias="MyTypeAlias" type="ProductModel.IProduct, ProductModel"/>
</typeAliases>
</unity>
```

The typeAlias element gives a ‘short-name’ for a type. This ‘short-name’ can be used to point to this type any where in the configuration file.

Comment: Yes, but how could I use those type aliases in my WCF service xml configuration?

Comment: Indeed the type aliased defined for unity can be used across all configuration, even in WCF's <client> or <endpoint>. Only problem we are using Spring.NET. But thanks.